# How to access protected variable in child class

Tags: python

I have class A:

```
class A:
    _useful: dict
...
```

and class B which inherits from A:

```
class B(A):
    def foo(self, key, value):
        super()._useful.update({key: value})
...
```

However I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '_useful'
```

Comment: Please give a [mre] - is that attribute _initialised_ anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialize the dictionary, try this

```
class A:
    _useful: dict = dict()
```